# always giving password not strong enough message (else condition is running)

Tags: bash

I have been working on this function in shell scripting to take up a password from a user and check if it satisfies the criteria of being an effective password but it always says password not strong enough. The password I'm trying to use is `LK@12abc`.

Here is my code:

```
function paq()
{   

     read -p "PASSWORD :-" password

     pasq="^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8}$"

    if [[ $password =~ $pasq ]]; then
          echo "Valid password"
          echo "The password is:- $password" >> user1.txt
          echo "$password" >>password.txt
    else
          echo "password not strong enough"
    fi
}
paq
```

Comment: Using a regex that meets all conditions will be hard to write, and very difficult to debug and maintain. Perhaps you should make different functions like `has_uppercase()`, `has_lowercase()`, `has_specials()`, `has_digits`, `has_minlength` and `has_forbidden()`. Using these functions is more code, but will be easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for including a self contained test case. You can additionally make it minimal by removing all the code not required to show the problem. In your case, `[[ x =~ (?=x).* ]] || echo "Why does this fail to match?"` would have been enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your password has to have:

- 3 lower case letters
- 2 upper case letters
- 2 digits
- 1 punctuation character
- exactly 8 characters long

So, with bash glob patterns:

```
if [[ $password == *[a-z]*[a-z]*[a-z]* ]] &&
   [[ $password == *[A-Z]*[A-Z]* ]] &&
   [[ $password == *[0-9]*[0-9]* ]] &&
   [[ $password == *[!@#$\&*]* ]] &&
   (( ${#password} == 8 ))
then
    echo password OK
else
    echo password does not satisfy criteria
fi
```

I'm surprised that I need to escape the `&` in the 4th test

Answer (score 0):

As it says in `man bash`:

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same
>   precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of
>   the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched
>   accordingly (as in regex(3)).

The first problem is that `POSIX` regex does not allow for lookahead
and lookbehing assertions.

The second problem is that your test password is not correct - you
miss 8 random characters at the end.

The third problem is that you didn't specify the
[`shebang`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and didn't quote variables correctly.

All in all, your script should look like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

paq() {

    read -r -p "PASSWORD :- " password

    pasq="^(.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(.*[!@#$&*])(.*[0-9].*[0-9])(.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8}$"

    if [[ "$password" =~ $pasq ]]; then
    echo "Valid password"
    echo "The password is:- $password" >> user1.txt
    echo "$password" >>password.txt
    else
    echo "password not strong enough"
    fi

}

paq
```

Run it:

```
$ ./paq.sh
PASSWORD :- AB!11abc12345678
Valid password
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . although I did use shebang but forgot to mention it in my snippet.

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as accepted to let other users know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yhe password `11abc12345678AB` is invalid according to your code. You check the upper case characters first. And you want 8 random characters after matching the 4 patterns (with `.{8}`).

Comment: I use `AB!11abc12345678`. There should be a whitespace after `PASSWORD :-`. I added the whitespace.

Comment: Try the following passwords with your code: `11abc12345678AB` and `AB!11abc1234567`.

Comment: Both fail.  The password I used in my answer is correct. I don't get the point.  I didn't come up with a new algorithm, OP cannot use `~=` if he wants to use look ahead assertion, I suggest `perl`.

Comment: OP want to see if a password matches the conditions: minimal 8 length, with one upper, one lowercase character, a digit and a special char. When you want to match this with one regex, you need to `(..|..|..)` all permutions for the different orders. Alternative: You can check `^([A-Z!@#$&*0-9a-z]){8,}$` first and each character set  separate, or try to sort the characters in the passwd first.

Comment: @WalterA: Thank you for your input.  You may be right that this is what OP really want but it wasn't immediately clear to me. Feel free to correct my answer or write your own and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your original regex and feed it to `grep -P` (only if your system's `grep` supports Perl regular expressions). Then use the script:

```
while ! echo "$password" | grep -P '^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8}$'
do                                                                       
    read -r -p "PASSWORD: " password                                     
    echo -e "Password not strong enough, it needs\n\                     
            3 lower case letters\n\                                      
            2 upper case letters\n\                                      
            2 digits\n\                                                  
            1 punctuation character\n\                                   
            exactly 8 characters long\n"                                 
done                                                                     
echo "Valid password"                                                    
echo "The password is:- $password" | tee user1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tr` to translate each wanted character classes to a digit, `sort`ing that digit string and count matching with `grep` (using @glennjackman defined character classes except the exact length):

```
echo LK@12abc | 
tr '[:digit:]' 1 |                         # do this first
tr '[:upper:]' 2 | 
tr '[:lower:]' 3 | 
tr '[:punct:]' 4 | 
tr -c '[:digit:]' 5 |                      # all else to 5
grep -o . |                                # transpose
sort |                                     # sort
tr -d '\n' |                               # transpose 
if 
  grep -q  "1\{2,\}2\{2,\}3\{3,\}4\{1,\}5" # 5 is the trailing newline
then 
  echo yes
else 
  echo no
fi                                         # outputs
yes
```

( I was trying to `tr '[:digit:][:upper:][:lower:]' '123'` but apparently that won't work so each class is now processed on its own line. Maybe you could loose the `tr`s, just sort the password string and count match classes with `grep`)